# How can I show a generated image on when the UWP app is opened?

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to generate a fractal image and show the image when the app is loaded. It works for events like clicking a button and resizing the window, but not when the app is first opened.

The XAML is:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Scenario4ImageContainer"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" PointerPressed="Scenario4ImageContainer_PointerPressed">
    <Image x:Name="Scenario4Image" />
</Viewbox>
```

The code is:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        generator.Width = (int)imageColumn.ActualWidth; ;
        generator.Height = (int)imageRow.ActualHeight; ;
        generator.InitMap();
        generator.Generate();

        fractalBitmap = await colorer.Color(generator.Map);

        Scenario4Image.Source = fractalBitmap;
        fractalBitmap.Invalidate();

        //This works...
        //Scenario4Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png"));
    }
```

Comment: As a note, you don't need to put the Image control in a Viewbox. Just set the Image control's Stretch property appropriately. Besides that, did you check if `imageColumn.ActualWidth` and `imageRow.ActualHeight` are greater than zero?

Comment: I've checked and the width and height are definitely greater than zero. They are the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wait for the Windows to be activated ? 
You could expose a method in your App.xaml.cs file using a TaskCompletionSource :

```
private static TaskCompletionSource _waitActivation =new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

public static Task WaitWindowActivationAsync(){
    return _waitActivation.Task;
}

private void OnLaunched(...){

 ...

 Windows.Current.Activate();

_waitActivation.TrySetResult(true);

}
```

Then in your handler, you call it :

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       await App.WaitWindowActivationAsync(); 
       ...
    }
```

You could also add a wait to Task.Yield(); :

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       await Task.Yield();
       await App.WaitWindowActivationAsync(); 
       ...
    }
```

Comment: I was able to add the code in App.xaml.cs by adding a type to TaskCompletionSource 

`private static TaskCompletionSource<bool> _waitActivation = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();`

But was unable to call it in the Page_Loaded method. I don't have access to the App variable there. Maybe something changed with the newer version of UWP app?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the mistake in my code : make the WaitWindowActivationAsync method static and call it from the loaded event handler. Tell me if it works.